# Energy Levels in Bohr's Diagram

Tags: electrons, valence-bond-theory

When drawing the Bohr Diagram of Potassium with 19 electrons, the valence electron goes in the fourth concentric circle, but third energy level can hold up to 18 electrons? Does it mean that subsequent elements like Scandium will go back to the third energy level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bohr energy levels (quantum number n) are valid for atoms or ions with a single electron only, otherwise they split up and differ for different orbital types (quantum number l).

So the 4th, 5th levels start to fill before the prior level is filled, as 3d(4d) orbitals have higher energy than 4s(5s) orbitals.  Similarly, the 6th, 7th levels start to fill before prior 2 levels are filled, as described in [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle).

The general (with exceptions) orbital filling order is 1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, 5s, 4d, 5p, 6s, 4f, 5d, 6p, 7s, 5f, 6d, 7p.  The respective orbital groups ns, np, nd, nf may contain up to 2, 6, 10, 14 electrons.

See also [atomic orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital)

Comment: ok that's what I suspected that subsequent energy levels get filled before prior level. Do you used "Bohr energy level" and "electron shell" interchangeably?

Comment: It can be used that way, but I haven't used the term electron shell as I rather avoid it. It creates false impression electrons are organized in some spheres. Bohr model is obsolete for almost 100 years and is taught mainly for its simplicity and for historical reasons.